# Strange keyboard issues when using vncserver using kde

Tags: server, keyboard, kubuntu, kde, tightvncserver

I have installed ubuntu server 17.10 on one box, and then installed kde and tightvncserver on it using:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y kubuntu-desktop tightvncserver`

I can get a server started just fine, and can get connected, but the keyboard input seems to be off. It appears that the keyboard mapping is off when connecting from my client (using Remmina on Ubuntu 16.04). When typing in the terminal within the connected window, I get gibberish (wrong keys when pressed, etc.).

A strange quirk of this issue is that I can seemingly type fine in the firefox window in the remote desktop.

I am also sometimes getting some strange visual artifacts around some text in the 'start menu', as well as 'drkonqi' crashing repeatedly.

I have tried going through the keyboard settings (in the remote session), to see about changing the mappings, with no luck. Currently using 'generic 104 key PC'.

I am assuming I might be missing a step somewhere?

Comment: This may not be all that helpful, but for my purposes I wanted KDE on my remote machine as well. I read some horror stories wrt kubuntu-desktop, and used kde-plasma-desktop instead. I'm running x11vnc without issue - although I had to manually compile my own version (of x11vnc) to work around a bug.

Comment: Very helpful! What was the bug?

Comment: Stack smashing caused service restarts that disconnected the client. I built it without GCC stack protection, not risky for a local network only deployment, otherwise not recommended.

Comment: Gotcha... I don't intend to stack smash so I will give the straight install a shot tonight.

Comment: By the way, x11vnc doesn't work on Wayland.

Comment: Tried `kde-plasma-desktop`, still with tightvncserver, seems to have the same issues

Comment: Running Ubuntu 18.04.3 and installed KDE desktop env. and RealVNC (virtual mode daemon).  When I connect to that machine using RealVNC Viewer, I get a notification that "drkonqi Closed Unexpectedly".  journamctl indicates gnome-software[2012]: failed to rescan: Failed to parse /usr/share/applications/org.kde.drkonqi.desktop file: cannot process file of type application/x-desktop
systemd[1]: vncserver-virtuald.service: Found left-over process 2343 (drkonqi) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
I can 'solve" by removing drkonqi, but looking for a better way.